# `conda info -a` not showing the PATH I am trying to add

Tags: python, path, conda

I am working inside a Conda environment and trying to add a location to PATH.

The reason is that I want to import a script in the parent directory of the script being run.

Directory I am working in:
`C:/Users/.../gompertz_forecasting`

Directory of script (being run):
`c:/Users/.../gompertz_forecasting/src/pre_processing/pre_processing_factors.py`

Directory of script imported:
`c:/Users/.../gompertz_forecasting/src/staging/generate_factors.py`

I am importing using the command
`from src.staging.generate_factors import x,y,z`

However, I keep getting the message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'"
even though I have added the directory to both the Path and PYTHONPATH via the Windows System Properties.

So, while the path has been added, I still cannot import the module.
When I print `conda info -a` the added path fails to show up as part of PATH, which is what I believe the issue is.

Expected solution is to simply run
`conda develop C:\Users\...\gompertz_forecasting\src` but this does not add the directory to the PATH. It is still missing when running `conda info -a` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inside `conda` environment make sure to run `conda` develop from within the same environment. If it still dont work lets try to manually add the path to your `PYTHONPATH` from within Python before you import the module.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\...\gompertz_forecasting\src")

from staging.generate_factors import x, y, z
```

Comment: I was running `conda develop` from within the environment, and tried it outside too, both did not work. Your solution of `sys.path.append` solved the problem for me though. Many thanks!